# how to assign a role to user for Specified time, asp.net mvc5, Identity 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, role

how to assign a role to user for Specified time (for example 10 day) using asp.net mvc5, Identity 2.0

I think we can do it by adding an expiration field to AspNetUsersRoles table like below, but I dont know how?

[AspNetUsersRoles](https://pasteboard.co/HgJq8Z1i.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I would keep Identity intact and use antoher table to store that (Extension Table).
With that, the additionnal table would store FK_UserRole and a Date.

Then you can check the date of the person on each conneciton of this person and remove the role if neccessary.